# Read bills from a bills.csv file

Tags: python, homework

I wrote the following code to read out a bill from a file and then putting it into a bills-list.

The bill contains: "company", "customer", Year, Month, Day, Amount, "credit/debit"

Is there a nicer way using list comprehension to make this code look better?

```
def read_bills(file = "bills.csv"):
    """Read bills from the file system 'bills.csv'"""
    # Create a list in which each bill is entered.
    bills = []
    for line in open(file):
        bill = line.strip().split(',')
        for i in range(len(bill)):
            if i > 1 and i < 5:
                bill[i] = int(bill[i].strip())
            elif i == 5:
                bill[i] = float(bill[i].strip())
            else:
                bill[i] = bill[i].strip()
        bills.append(bill)
    return bills
```

[image]

Comment: Use Pandas? That will make this one line.

Comment: Can't use panadas unfortunately

Comment: And why would that be? Is this for school?

Comment: Also: it's good that you've told us your columns, but can you show us the first few lines of a file?

Comment: Yes, and I added a screenshot of the first few lines of a file.

Comment: Screenshots are useless; please post a few lines of a file **as text**, including header line….

Comment: Pandas may be a bit heavy for this but why not use the built-in Python [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) ? It appears that you are parsing a simple CSV file so there is no need for a fancy line parsing routine. Plus, using a [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) you could use column names. This would be so much more straightforward.

Comment: When you try to parse CSV by splitting, you are doing it wrong. Try the implementation on [this CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Example).

Answer (score 6):

The least appealing, most tedious part of the current code is the conditional
logic to handle data conversion. Since you're dealing with a limited number of
columns, you can use a data structure to eliminate the conditionals. (In my
experience, smarter or more convenient/suitable data structures are often the
most powerful devices to simplify algorithmic logic.) For example, to parse a
single line, one could write something like this:

```
def parse_line(line):
    types = (str, str, int, int, int, float, str)
    raw_vals = [val.strip() for val in line.strip().split(',')]
    return [f(val) for val, f in zip(raw_vals, types)]
```

And if that line-parsing function existed, the overall bill-parsing
function would be pretty trivial:

```
def read_bills(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as fh:
        return [parse_line(line) for line in fh]
```

Don't overlook the implicit suggestion here: separate the detailed logic (line
parsing) from larger orchestration (opening a file and processing it line by
line). The latter can usually be quite simple, hardly worth testing or worrying
about too much, while the former often requires more effort to ensure
correctness. Reducing the footprint of the code requiring in-depth testing
is usually a good move to make.

Comment: I don't believe you need the `.strip()` in `line.strip().split(',')` as each value is stripped after the split.

Comment: @benh Only the no-argument form of `str.split()` includes the auto-magical behavior of also removing whitespace surrounding the delimiter. For example, do some experimenting with this: `'Foo Bar, Blah, 123'.split(',')`. Alas, further stripping is required. One could do it all in a single split by using `re.split()`, but I probably wouldn't take that route -- extra complexity with little benefit.

Answer (score 4):

Overlapping somewhat with @FMc:

- Probably should avoid making a `bills` list; just use a generator
- Use the built-in `csv` and `dataclass` modules to make your life easier
- Prefer a deserialization routine that uses column names instead of column indices.
- I see that you're using `float` for your billed amount but this is not appropriate. For monetary numerics use `Decimal` unless you have a very good reason.
- Make an actual date object out of your date fields.

### Suggested

```py
from csv import DictReader
from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import date
from decimal import Decimal
from typing import Any, TextIO, Iterator


@dataclass
class BillLine:
    company: str
    customer: str
    when: date
    amount: Decimal

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, data: dict[str, Any]) -> 'BillLine':
        when = date(
            int(data['Year']),
            int(data['Month']),
            int(data['Day']),
        )

        amount = Decimal(data['Amount'])
        if amount < 0:
            raise ValueError('Negative amount disallowed; use "debit"')

        credit = data['credit/debit']
        if credit == 'debit':
            amount = -amount
        elif credit != 'credit':
            raise ValueError(f'"{credit}" is an unrecognized credit state')

        return cls(
            company=data['company'],
            customer=data['customer'],
            when=when, amount=amount,
        )

    @classmethod
    def from_csv(cls, file: TextIO) -> Iterator['BillLine']:
        csv = DictReader(file)
        for record in csv:
            yield cls.from_dict(record)


def test() -> None:
    with open('bills.csv', newline='') as file:
        records = tuple(BillLine.from_csv(file))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```